# HTML element for importing semantic (linked) data

Tags: html, semantic-web, linked-data

I want to include some semantic information of another website in my own site (for reusing the information instead of copying it). Is there a standardized HTML tag for this? (like it is possible with videos, images, etc.)

As an example, let's take some code from schema.org:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
  <span itemprop="name">Blend-O-Matic</span>
  <span itemprop="price">$19.95</span>
  <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock"/>Available today!
</div>
```

Now, I want to include the price information in my site. How can I do this? (I imagined to use something like this *`<information src="..." type="microdata" attributes="price" query="name=Blend-O-Matic" type="http://schema.org/Offer"/>`* but haven't found anything.)

Answer (score 0):

HTML doesn’t offer something like this. The equivalent of `img`/`video`/etc. would be `iframe`, but this only allows displaying the whole HTML document, not just a specific part of it.

On the level of structured data (e.g., using Microdata, or RDF serializations like RDFa and JSON-LD), you can refer to another thing by referencing [that thing’s URI](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/98578/17633) (if the publisher defined one), but not to a property of that thing.

If you want to display the data on your page, you have to

1. get the data (scraping, API, SPARQL, …),
2. include the data (either on the client-side with JavaScript, or on the server-side with a programming language of your choice), and
3. regularly check the original source for updates.